# Vue JS: how to get nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have JSON like below, in payment .. i can't get cash_payment's `paid_amount` or installment_payment's `paid_amount` and date as well

```html
{
    "response": [
        {
            "status": "sold",
            "price": "100000",
            "currency": "USD",
            "_id": "61c21fa6f650480b7630badf",
            "flat_number": 1,
            "description": "This is a newly created flat.",
            "city": "dokj",
            "payment": {
                "cash_payment": {
                    "paid_amount": "100000",
                    "date": "2021-12-23"
                }
            },
            "floor": "61c21fa6f650480b7630bade",
            "building": "61c21fa6f650480b7630badd",
            "createdAt": "2021-12-21T18:40:44.200Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-12-23T18:42:43.959Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "status": "sold",
            "price": "Not set",
            "currency": "USD",
            "_id": "61c21fa6f650480b7630bae0",
            "flat_number": 2,
            "description": "This is a newly created flat.",
            "city": "Istanbul",
            "payment": {
                "installment_payment": {
                    "installments": [
                        {
                            "paid_amount": "5000",
                            "date": "2021-12-21"
                        },
                        {
                            "paid_amount": "4000",
                            "date": "2021-12-21"
                        }
                    ],
                    "remaining": "1000"
                }
            },
            "floor": "61c21fa6f650480b7630bade",
            "building": "61c21fa6f650480b7630badd",
            "createdAt": "2021-12-21T18:40:44.202Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-12-22T23:06:26.602Z",
            "__v": 0
        },}
```

code below:

```js
<template>
<div>
    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header bg-gradient-success py-7 py-lg-8 pt-lg-9">
        <b-container>
            <div class="header-body text-center mb-7">
                <b-row class="justify-content-center">
                    <b-col xl="5" lg="6" md="8" class="px-5">

                    </b-col>
                </b-row>
            </div>
        </b-container>

    </div>
    <!-- Page content -->
    <b-container class="page-contet mt--8 pb-5">
        <b-row class="justify-content-center">
            <b-col lg="7" md="10">
                <b-card no-body class="bg-white border-0 mb-0" style="background: linear-gradient(87deg, #172b4d 0, #1d2026 100%) !important ;">
                    <b-card-header class="bg-transparent pb-5">
                        <div class="text-muted text-center mt-2 mb-3">
                            <h2> details </h2>
                           
                        </div>

                    </b-card-header>
                    <b-card-body class="px-lg-5 py-lg-5" v-if="roles ==='Admin'">
                        <div class="text-center text-muted mb-4">

                        </div>
                        <validation-observer ref="formValidator">
                            <b-form role="form">
                                <select class="status-info" v-model="City">
                                    <option value="" selected disabled> choose city </option>
                                    <option value="duhok" >doki</option>
                                  >
                                </select>


                                <div v-if="City=='duhok'" v-for="(flat,index) in Flats" :key="index" v-show="flat.city=='doki'">
                                {{flat.city}} // i can get city easily
                               <pre style="color:white;" v-for="(find,indexT) in flat" :key="indexT"> {{find.paid_amount}}  </pre> //didn't work
                             
                                </div>
                            
                            </b-form>
                        </validation-observer>
                    </b-card-body>
                </b-card>

            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import BuildingsService from "../../../services/ApiService"
export default {
    name: 'light-table',
    components: {

    },
    data() {
        return {
           
            buildingId: this.$route.params.id,
           
            Flats: [],
           City:"",
            Floors: [],
            check: true,
            Building: [],
            obj:[],
            paymentObj:""
           
           

        };
    },
    computed: {
        roles() {
            let roles = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user')).role;
            return roles;
        },
      
    },

    mounted: function () {

        BuildingsService.getAllFlats().then((response) => {
            this.Flats = response.data.response;

        });

        BuildingsService.getBuildings().then((response) => {
            this.Building = response.data.response;

            console.log(this.Building, "buildings");

        });

    },

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
find.payment.cash_payment.paid_amount
find.payment.installment_payment.installments[0].paid_amount
find.payment.installment_payment.installments[1].paid_amount
```

You will need a method to detect the payment method and also sum the installments if it is an array.

Non tested example

```
getPaidAmount(flat) {
 if (flat.payment.cash_payment){ return Number(payment.cash_payment.paid_amount) }
 if (flat.payment.installment_payment){ 
   const arr = flat.payment.installment_payment.installments.map(it=>Number(it.paid_amount))
   const sum = arr.reduce(function (a, b) {return a + b;}, 0);
   return sum
  }
}
```